# NativeProcess fails to run C# WPF application on windows

Tags: c#, wpf, process, air

OK

We have a Adobe Air (AS3) application that runs our WPF application. but WPF application fails to run by this way. i found following error message in `EventViewer`:

```
Faulting application name: Easysoft_MultiTouch_Document.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4f0f2f9e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000aa7d
Faulting process id: 0xeac
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccd20c9e406d25
Faulting application path: E:\Apps\PDFProgram\Easysoft_MultiTouch_Document.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dc656dc1-3dff-11e1-8870-00268330b66c
```

and here is the Adobe Air code to run WPF application:

```
// following condition is true 
 if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
        {
        var file:File = new File("E:\\Apps\\GalleryProgram\\Easysoft_MultiTouch_Document.exe");
        trace(file.name);
        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

        var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();


        process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
        //....
   }
```

I wrote another C# application to run this WPF executable file, but it fails too.

How fix this problem? Can WPF applications run by this way? any solution?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you able to run your WPF application under normal startup conditions (e.g. double-click the .exe file)?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll WPF applicaiton runs successfully by double clicking on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular exception code you're seeing from the process is 0xe0434352.  That's indicative of a managed exception being thrown.  This means it's very likely that the WPF process is starting, at least getting to the point of loading the CLR and running managed code, and then throwing an unhandled managed exception.

This means the fault is most likely in the WPF application.  Have you verified that it can run on it's own on the box?  If so then I would setup the debugger to attach on start for the application, run the scenario through the Adobe Air and see why this process is crashing.

Comment: WPF applicaiton runs successfully by double clicking on it! the error dialog box is windows error box. if an unhandled managed exception was thrown, CLR exception dialog should be appear.

Comment: @JalalAmini the next step I would take is setup the debugger to start on process start and debug it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I would try introducing a choke-point in the WPF application and log the exception to a text file, so that you have additional information about the error, something like this:

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

Then, in the callback, write any exception details to a file:

```
    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsTerminating)
        {
            // Add your logging code here.
        }
    }
```

This way you would have more information about the reason behind the crash and you could go grom there.